# Does Facebook have a complaint site that redirects to SO?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, facebook

Seriously though, there are several posts tagged [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) on SO that are by people trying to use facebook.com.

Examples from the past few hours (all now 10k-only):

- [Can you CHANGE my Facebook profile, EVERYTHING back to the way it was?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494831/can-you-change-my-facebook-profile-everything-back-to-the-way-it-was/7494962)
- [Can I change my news feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501331/can-i-change-my-news-feed)
- [Status updates in News feed on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502747/status-updates-in-news-feed-on-facebook)
- [How to recover my facebook app? Admin role removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504898/how-to-recover-my-facebook-app-admin-role-removed)
- [Hey facebook I'm sick of you changing every two weeks and changing our relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506515/hey-facebook-im-sick-of-you-changing-every-two-weeks-and-changing-our-relation)

Does anyone have an idea why all these people come here, or, better yet, how to detect these sorts of posts automatically to prevent them from cluttering us up?

Comment: See [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/).

Comment: @Matthew: Well, that certainly explains a lot.

Comment: Facebook users always have a knack for finding the wrong door

Comment: Look at my profile.

Comment: Another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600287/i-have-an-issue-with-my-photos-section one

Comment: ...and another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810387/username-url-needs-to-be-removed-asap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that registration, as of a few days ago, is now *mandatory* to ask questions.

This was partially done to assist with the Facebook issue.

(other reasons: to put yet another barrier in front of question askers to help with general quality, and to assist new askers in getting a registered account so they don't create dupe unregistered accounts, etc.)

Comment: The mandatory registration affects only Stack Overflow it seems - any plans to make it mandatory on other high-traffic SE sites?

Answer (score 4):

Vote to close them and flag them for a moderator.  They usually get closed in a matter of minutes. There isn't much else that can be done. There is already a [big warning message](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) when the user clicks ask a question (open in incognito window).

Comment: I do, but 8 such questions within 3 hours is rather obnoxious. At this point, I'm probably going to mark `facebook` as an ignored tag.

Comment: @PengOne You might want to use wildcards (`facebook*`) to ignore them all

Comment: Today has been bad because Facebook changed their layout and every time they do there is a massive protest.  But people will get over it and those questions will slow here.

Comment: That *big warning message* seems to not have the part about programming only as way too small. Needs to be 72pt font. Maybe they should have to complete a small programming task, like "there are ___ types of people who understand binary. A) 1 B) 2 C) 10 D) False".

Answer (score 1):

I have definitely seen an increase in Facebook support questions here, even since mandatory signup. One guy even claimed that there was a link to SO on the password recovery page. When I asked him for the link he replied:

> "I don't have time for that, just give me the answer"!

Nice. But that question's since been deleted, it seems.

As the **[ReadWriteWeb 'incident'](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/02/12/google_de_facto_internet_gateway/)** showed us*, the (worryingly large) mouth-breathing subset of Facebook users who type "Facebook login" into *Google* so they can log in to Facebook.com have no lower bound on stupidity when it comes to using the internet.

I don't know which is worse - *trying* to ask SO to reset your Facebook password, or ***actually signing up for an SO account*** and ***then*** asking for your password to be reset.

Either way, I fear for the herds of Facebook zombies at the door of SO.

---

*If you didn't read about it at the time, please do! It will make you laugh and despair in equal measure. The actual article is still there: [www.readwriteweb.com](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/facebook_wants_to_be_your_one_true_login.php)