# Facebook complaints on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, questions, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Facebook have a complaint site that redirects to SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106976/does-facebook-have-a-complaint-site-that-redirects-to-so)

There have been a lot of complaints on Stack Overflow from people posting with the assumption that we are Facebook support; for example, they complain we would have the ability to make somebody's friends list work right.

I wouldn't have thought anything about it, but there have been so many lately that it's almost as if Facebook users are being referred to us by somebody or some website.

Has anybody seen or heard anything that would suggest that we can fix any Facebook problem, like these people seem to think?

Comment: About a week or so ago, there were at least 3 complaints on SO about the layout changing. They were more like flaming posts. There wasn't a single question in any of them. They were clearly angry and they were just complaining about how much they hated the changes blah blah blah...

Comment: Ah... Didn't see that one. Thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: Which is why I added `facebook*` to my Ignored Tags list.  I wonder how many other SO users have done this.

Comment: @jay we require registration to ask questions now, partly based on that.. as of a few days ago. So observations from 7+ days ago probably aren't valid any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People think that because (quoting from the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)):

> So when the largest social developer platform in the world came to us and said they wanted to partner with us, we were all ears.  And because of that partnership, we are proud to announce that facebook.stackoverflow.com is launching today as the new official developer support channel for all Facebook developers.

Note that `facebook.` just filters on Facebook related tags, it's part of Stack Overflow.

People get confused between "developer support" and general support. That's why you're seeing tons of off-topic Facebook questions.